# x - qTranslate language will not be saved on browser shutdown

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate-x

When a frontend changes the language, this change will probably not be stored in a cookie after you close your browser and re-open a page. I open an incorrect version information is  saved into them about me sometimes and it often happens that when you once the site switches to PL, then the nearest week, the least I opens PL although I have meanwhile already several times changed the language to SK.

Comment: I fixed it with this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618636/qtranslate-for-wordpress-doesnt-automatic-give-me-the-correct-language

Answer (score 0):

But for firefox not fixed it, firefox still get bad cookie.

Sample:

**If first time on website SK, in console/storage is value SK.
But if i change to EN. Its change on EN, its good.
But if I go back on SK language, in console/storage is value set to EN.
If i go to PL language, value change to PL.
If i go back to SK, value still PL. Not change to SK. BTW SK is default language.**